# PHP-FPM Active Processes are high(zabbix) how to edit this Expression?

Tags: php, zabbix, agent

In the past few days, my Zabbix agent on a specific web server is triggering alerts every few minutes.

I have this Expression

```
{Template App PHP-FPM:service.phpfpm.status[activeProcesses].last()}>20
```

This is the basic template for PHP-FPM.
how can I edit this so it will be:
if the active process is high for 5 minutes then send the alert?

Answer (score 0):

you can fire the alert when the maximum value, within 5 minutes, is more than 20

```
{Template App PHP-FPM:service.phpfpm.status[activeProcesses].max(5m)}>20
```

Comment: .avg(5m) maybe is more considerate, avoid triggering for "spikes"